# Parallax scrolling function doesn't work perfectly

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

The parallax scrolling function is slightly off. When you click on a top-level navigation, it should take you down the page to where the section is, but it's off for some reason. 
Example- When I click on "register' on the top level nav, it doesn't quite take me to the registration form.

I set menu as-

```
<a href="http://www.url.com#contact">Register</a>
```

& section as-

```
<section id="contact">
........
</section>
```

Comment: Can you try `<a href="http://www.url.com/#contact">Register</a>`

Comment: " it doesn't quite take me to the registration form" **where does it take you?

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
<a href="http://www.url.com#contact">Register</a>
```

then instead of the `<section>`  use `<a name="contact" > ...`